# [SOLVED] opencv my awesome library problem

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a problem when trying to run catkin_make, i am trying to build a package that uses opencv, i have added in CMakeLists :
find_package(OpenCV)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
   target_link_libraries(my_awesome_library ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
but running catkin_make i get the folowing problem:

CMake Error at wificam/CMakeLists.txt:168 (target_link_libraries):
Cannot specify link libraries for target "my_awesome_library" which is not
built by this project.

any idead what can I do? thanks a lot

EDIT 1:
this is it

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(wificam)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  roscpp
  std_msgs
  image_transport
  camera_info_manager

)


catkin_package(

)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)



find_package(OpenCV)
   include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
   #target_link_libraries(my_awesome_library ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(wificamp src/wificamp.cpp)
target_link_libraries(wificamp ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(wificampc src/wificampc.cpp)
target_link_libraries(wificampc ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(wificampb src/wificampb.cpp)
target_link_libraries(wificampb ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(wificams src/wificams.cpp)
target_link_libraries(wificams ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(testbridge src/testbridge.cpp)
target_link_libraries(testbridge ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

it is comented because if not i could not build it, how should I define that cmake target? I thought i had done it like it is explained in the opencv ros tutorial, i am still a noob sorry and thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201718/%5Bsolved%5D-opencv-my-awesome-library-problem/) by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2015-01-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sort of error indicates that you haven't defined a cmake target called `my_awesome_library`.

The name of your cmake target is the first argument to `add_executable(...)` or `add_library(...)`.

It may be useful to edit your question to include your full CMakeLists.txt if you would like more help.

**EDIT**

Your first CMake target is name `wificamp`; therefore your linking command should be:

```
target_link_libraries(wificamp ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
```

You can also combine this with the linking command that links your exectuable against the catkin libraries:

```
target_link_libraries(wificamp ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2